# How can I create a new array from an original array making use of ONE MORE DIFFERENT ARRAY in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, filter

Here are two simple arrays, one is an original list, the other is a selected index from the original one.
I just want to re-create a new array, based on the selected index array.

Here is my code.

```
const list = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Ken"
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Ryu"
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Sakura"
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Vega"
}
]

const index = [1, 3]

//I want to get a new array like this, making use of both of the arrays above:
filterdList = [
 {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ryu"
 },
 {
    id: 3,
    name: "Vega"
 }   
]
```

I tried lots of things but I just messed up and was just stack.
How would you accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to filter by index or id?

Comment: Was "by using id" what the other answer used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const list=[{id:0,name:"Ken"},{id:1,name:"Ryu"},{id:2,name:"Sakura"},{id:3,name:"Vega"},];

const index = [1, 3];

const filteredList = list.filter(({id}) => index.includes(id))

console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I really didn't know you can extract the actual key(here, it's 'id')by using the destructure method with filter. That's also good to learn.